# Can I ask a question before I screw up?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Back to programming after a 10+ year hiatus. One of the great changes is Stack Overflow.

QUESTION: When architecting, I can often think of three or four ways to do something. I can try each one and see which is best suited to the overall design. This takes time. Or, I can tap into the SO community and ask which works best given certain constraints and purposes. However, I'm not sure if that will be perceived as a lazy question......it is a lazy question, but it is also a fairly efficient way to get stuff done.

Opinions welcome

Comment: Or even one of the chat rooms? Definitely not a good fit for a Q&A site.

Comment: @Patrice - Programmers has the same restrictions on too broad or opinion based questions as Stack Overflow. Please don't suggest sites you're not familiar with as alternatives.

Comment: This is a question for chat (or forum), not a Q/A site. The reason Stack Overflow is a great change is that questions like your suggestion get closed/removed...

Comment: @Patrice see: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat thanks. I did say "maybe" because I was unsure. Next time I guess I'll have to be more direct in how I phrase that maybe

Answer (score 21):

Stack Overflow (and the rest of Stack Exchange) is about **answerable** questions.

Asking us to choose between three approaches is *most of the time* not answerable. We don't know enough about your environment, it would take too long to test, etc. There might be disagreement about which is the best approach, or the reasons might be too broad, etc.

Additionally, future users will likely never be in your exact situation, so the knowledge provided probably won't be of future help, which is a big part of the Stack Exchange model.

Simply, such questions are almost never good fits and will get downvoted and/or closed. Instead, try one approach and ask us about the specific problem you have with it; perhaps one of your alternate approaches might get suggested (or even one you haven't thought of!) and that would better serve everyone's interests.

Comment: Not just Stack Overflow, it's the ethos of Stack Exchange as a whole.

Comment: @ChrisF Of course, but OP asked here, not on MSE ;)

Comment: Indeed, but people are already suggesting other sites in the comments...

Answer (score 9):

> I can try each one and see which is best suited to the overall design. This takes time.

Yes, that's what architecture is. You can outsource this phase of a project, but then you can outsource development as well and you're out of a job.

Welcome back to the profession, but deciding which approach to take for a given problem is part of the job. You have a problem, then write down that problem and how you would like it solved (i.e. your requirements). Then for any possible solution that fulfills those requirements, you have to list the pros and cons. After you've done that, you can make a decision for which solution you'll pick. As you'll (re)gain the experience, you'll become better at doing this process in your head or fall back on previous encounters of comparable problems and available solutions.

SO is not the place to outsource that process.

Answer (score 4):

Asking others to choose the *best* option will never be answerable. Which is better, a 1992 Toyota Avalon or a 2013 Honda Pilot? How would I know?

I think you could still ask your questions if you adjusted what you were asking for. Rather than trying to find the "best" technology, ask for a comparison of two technologies over a particular feature.

For example, what are the differences between C# and Java's implementations of Generics, and what practical effect does it have on Reflection? That question may be a tad broad by some standards, but given some additional constraints and context, it becomes answerable. You could then make an informed decision to choose which is "best" in your opinion.